# Heroku 'unknown command' error

Tags: heroku

I have the following procfile:

```
web: phantomjs myscript.js
```

Now when I run:

```
../f/EasyPHP-12.1/www/MYPROJECT (master)
$ foreman start
22:09:28 web.1  | unknown command: phantomjs myscript.js
```

but

```
../f/EasyPHP-12.1/www/MYPROJECT (master)
$ foreman check
valid procfile detected (web)
```

if its valid why is the command unknown?

---

Answer (score 0):

Through I don't you what the command "phantomjs" is, it seems in your machine this "phantomjs" is not supported. Maybe you need install something to support the executing of "phantomjs". Just like you can't use linux "sh" command on windows platform if you haven't Cygwin installed...